# Mongoose Multiple Database For A single Application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

How can I access the *schema* of the other database in mongoose? 
E.g, `db1` has users list, `db2` has another list. My application has all the models defined only for `db1`. but now I want to access the list of `db2` in my application. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [useDb](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-useDb) function on `Connection` type. It returns another connection. If you share the same Schema then your code might look like below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test');

var schema = new Schema({
    // ...    
});

var db = mongoose.connection;
var Model1 = db.model('schema', schema, 'colName');

var db2 = db.useDb('test2');
var Model2 = db2.model('schema2', schema, 'colName');
```

Comment: `test2` is schema or database? For a database I should pass the connection URI right?

Comment: assuming you have the same URI then `test2` is just a database name (on the same server)